# How did “equivocal” come to mean what it means?

Tags: etymology

The word *unanimous* is reasonably easy to trace: it comes from Latin *unum* (one) + *anima* (mind). If several people are of the same unanimous opinion, they could be said to be speaking “of one mind”.

The word *equivocal* looks very similar. It comes from *aequi* (same) + *vocal* (from *vox*, voice). It would seem that it should mean “speaking with the same voice” and thus have a meaning similar to *unanimous*. Yet, it means the opposite, and it is *unequivocal* that is a synonym of *unanimous*.

**How did *equivocal* manage to reverse its meaning?**

Comment: What's for sure (and should be made explicit): the prefix "un-" in "unanimous" means something completely different (= unum = one) than in "unequivocal" (= not = other than). So the question is not very well posed, considering that "unequivocal" is a common term (meaning "unambiguous"). See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414941/equivocal-vs-unequivocal-vs-unambiguous-vs-ambiguous) for a related question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Equivocal* does not mean the opposite of *unanimous*, nor has it reversed its meaning.

For a person to *equivocate* is to use ambiguous language, and be non-committal: to "hedge" between two positions without committing to either, and ([literally](http://dictionary.reference.com/wordoftheday/archive/2009/09/21.html)) to "call equally one thing or the other" — to talk equally of two different positions.

*Equivocal* is the adjective form: an *equivocal* statement is one which talks equally of two different things, and does not take a clear single position. *Unequivocal* is the opposite: something with no ambiguity, something that does not equally emphasise two contradicting points, a strong message which leaves no doubt.

Note that these words are generally used to statements coming from one person; they are not (necessarily) related to whether an opinion is *unanimous* or not. *Unanimous* just means, as you said, that everyone shares the same opinion. So, when used for a statement made by a committee, all possibilities exist: it may be

- *unanimous* and *equivocal*: everyone endorsed a vague statement (most statements by government committees are probably examples)
- *unanimous* and *unequivocal*: a strong position that everyone shared
- *non-unanimous* and *equivocal*: not everyone agreed with the statement, probably because some of them wanted to pass a clear message instead
- *non-unanimous* and *unequivocal*: a strong message that not everyone agreed with.

So you see they are orthogonal, not opposites.

Comment: Heh, I think you got a bit bogged down trying to correct my misunderstanding of the meanings of the words, but you did also answer the actual question, so I’ll accept this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Timwi: Bogged down? :-) How? Was something in my answer unclear?

Comment: No, not unclear... just superfluous. I only used *unanimous* as an example for a word whose etymology is clear and similar — my actual question wasn’t about *unanimous* at all but only about *equivocal*. But like I said, you answered it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

To support ShreevatsaR's point and to address the actual origin of the word, here's what [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=equivocation) has to say:

> *equivocal* c.1600, from L.L. *aequivocus* "of equal voice, of equal significance, ambiguous" (see *equivocation*) [...]
>
> *equivocation*, late 14c., "the fallacy of using a word in different senses at different stages of the reasoning" (**a loan-transl. of Gk. *homonymia*, lit. "having the same name"**), from O.Fr. *equivocation*, from L.L. *aequivocationem* (nom. *aequivocatio*), from *aequivocus* "of identical sound," pp. of *aequivocare*, from *aequus* "equal" (see *equal*) + *vocare* "to call" (see *voice*).

Emphasis added. So *equivocal* never referred to "same voice", but rather to "identical sound". The difference might seem subtle, but it's crucial. *Equivocal* is not (and was never meant to be) about voicing the same opinion, but rather about voicing an opinion that could be taken to mean completely different things to different people.