# equivocal vs. unequivocal vs. unambiguous vs. ambiguous

Tags: etymology, synonyms, antonyms

The word "[equivocal](http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/equivocal.html)" sounds like "talking with the same (**one**) voice". But in the English language it seems to mean explicitly "[ambiguous](http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/ambiguous.html)" (= "talking with **two** voices/tongues/meanings").

> How can this be understood?

---

Having thought about it a bit longer, my guess is: "equivocal" means "of the same **sound** (but of *different* meanings)", not "of the same **voice** (= with the *same* meaning)".

The question then goes into this direction:

Did lat. "vox" semantically evolve into different directions, to mean more of a "**sound** (vocal)" (transporting possibly equivocal meanings) or more of a "**voice**" (transporting an unequivocal meaning).

---

Is there are deeper but comprehensible etymological origin of "vox"?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7545/how-did-equivocal-come-to-mean-what-it-means?rq=1